# SharePoint Server search connector framework and multi value fields

Tags: search

We have developed a SharePoint search connector that allows us to crawl and index an external content source.

It is based on the framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556429.aspx

Some of the fields crawled contain multiple values e.g. comma separated. SharePoint does not see these fields as multi valued.

We have created a managed property that maps to the crawled field and set it to "Has multiple values", but this does not appear to be working

Does anyone know how to have data crawled using the SharePoint Server search connector framework appear as a multi valued?

thanks

--

Thanks omlin for the tip.

The correct separator is ;#

Switching to use this in the data we are returning to SharePoint has enabled it to pick up the value as multi valued

Comment: usual separator for SharePoint is `#;`, you can try this.

Comment: @omlin: Look down there vvv (in case you haven't seen it).

Comment: great, I've hit it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks omlin for the tip.

The correct separator is ;#

Switching to use this in the data we are returning to SharePoint has enabled it to pick up the value as multi valued

Comment: @MBP, you should now accept your answer, to tell future readers that it is the correct one. And, feel free to ask any further questions here on SharePoint StackExchange :)